# Running Cboden Ratchet Websocket on the server

Tags: laravel, websocket, centos, firewall, ratchet

I made a chat service on my local machine and successfully ran it.
This chat service uses cboden retchat library and the custom JS on frontend.

So I uploaded everything on the CENTOS server and tried to run the chat.
I'm getting connection refused error. But I checked server firewall, opened ports (I changed the port from 8080 to 60000).
I tried to run server on this target:

```
0.0.0.0:60000
```

and connect from client like this

```
SERVERIP:60000
```

or

```
DOMAIN:60000
```

Tried to run server also as ROOT, but I get the same error.

Is it client firewall problem? How I fix it? I found a JS package, which connects to the chat server via 80 port and there is no firewall problems. I cannot use this package, because on our server we have one hundred services ran. So I decided to use the 60000 port.

I checked the port- it's free and unblocked.

My .env file

```
CHAT_PROTOCOL=wss://
CHAT_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
CHAT_PORT=60000
```

Client side JS

```
 var conn = new WebSocket(chat.protocol + SERVERIP +':'+ chat.port +'/chat');
//chat.protocol is wss://
//chat.port is 60000
```

Here is the problem

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://SERVERIP:60000/chat' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Again, it was perfect on my local machine (ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after 5 month.

My domain uses SSL connection so I should to include the CRT and KEY files by declaring the server variable.

```
const server = 
     require('https').createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/keys/************************.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certs/************************.crt'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certs/************************.crt'),
        requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },express);
```

Comment: it would be useful to specify what JS package you used, so that others can implement your solution.

Comment: @jgarcias nothing except Nodejs+ExpressJS